# My question was put on hold, need feedback.

Tags: discussion, on-hold-questions

this is a question I asked a few days ago:  [Lie Group has Euler characteristic zero.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3041622/lie-group-has-euler-characteristic-zero)

And it was put on hold.

As I understand it, from looking at the profiles of those who put it on hold, I have (maybe mistakenly) the assumption that it was because it is considered to be a ''help me do my homework'' question.

First I would like to advocate my post, maybe it would help on your feedback.

In all my previous posts, I had taken my time to show the work I had done, and my thoughts on the subject before posting, to show that I did actually put effort in solving it on my own. This question was from a past exam in my faculty, and I am about to take such exam, for me it is valid to ask about an exercise I really had no idea how to commence. And maybe I was missing some vital information or ''trick'' that would help me on future exercises.

So, this is why I did not put any ''I have tried this'' or something like that, because I really had no idea.

So.. what I need is feedback, am I wrong in doing this? What is the community's opinion on the subject of posting an exercise? And what should I do now? I know the site says to edit it in this type of situation, but my post was put on hold with already an accepted answer. The only edit I could think of, is posting the answer, but that seems like taking credit from the person who answered.

(Sorry if my english is sloppy, not my first language)

Comment: If you have accepted an answer, why do you want the question reopened?

Comment: You are right...just needed feedback for future posts.

Comment: Hey same profile logo almost. The questions are slightly different even if this one appeared two years later as a featured question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While I cannot speak for those that voted to close the question, my view is that it is a Problem Statement Question (PSQ) and that it lacks sufficient context.  The issue is not that it appears to be a homework question, but that the question contains nothing other than a problem that you want a solution to.  If you follow the ["provide additional context"](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) link in the close message, you can get some advice on how to improve your question.  Note that "Including Your Work" is only one of *many* things which you might consider doing.  Indeed, I would argue that showing your work is the worst way to add context.

Instead, explain where the problem came from.  Tell us why the problem is interesting to you and why we should care.  Cite your sources.  Give more detailed definitions.  Summarize any relevant theorems.